# While am I getting an error while setting up GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gkmatchmaker

I would like like to set up the matchmaking `viewController` of my game. To do so, I add the `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate` delegate to my main `UIViewController` called `Home`, so that it looks like:

```
class Home: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate {
```

To load up the matchmaking interface I am using this code:

```
func openMatchmaker() {
    var gcViewController: GKMatchmakerViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(rootViewController: self)

    gcViewController.matchmakerDelegate = self

    gcViewController.hosted = false
    gcViewController.matchRequest.minPlayers = 2
    gcViewController.matchRequest.maxPlayers = 2
    gcViewController.matchRequest.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2

    self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gcViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Though, I receive the following error next `class Home: ...` to when I try to run the code. The error message says:

```
 Type 'Home' does not conform to protocol `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate`.
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time when you get that error is because you have not implemented the required functions of the particular protocol. You can see them by command clicking on that protocol. Add the following methods:

```
func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!,
    didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
}

func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!,
    didFindHostedPlayers players: [AnyObject]!) {
}

func matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!) {
}

func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!,
    hostedPlayerDidAccept player: GKPlayer!) {
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer, thank you! I will be looking to implement these required methods asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The second function in the approved answer was updated in latest SDK:

```
func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFindHostedPlayers players: [GKPlayer]) {
   ... 
}
```